# Unpredictable nested div horizontal position in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-9, alignment

I am in no way an expert at HTML or CSS but I can ususally get my head around logical things. This has me stumped.

I nested a div (designed to carry a form) within a parent div. I set its position to absolute and bottom to zero so that it would appear at the bottom of the parent. I then specified margins to set the exact left and bottom indents I wanted.

When previewing in IE9 everything works fine but, after I uploaded and viewed on line, IE9 rendered the nested div way out to the right. Selecting compatability mode resolved the issue.

Now I floated the nested div left (within the parent) and the problem is reveresed. IE9 reders it fine, unless I select compatability mode.

This is my CSS:

```
.wrapper {float:left; width:100%; height:380px;background-image:url(../images/top_bck.png); background-repeat: repeat-x; background-position: top;}

.box {position:absolute; top:40%; left:50%;width:832px; height:553px;   margin:-180px 0 0 -416px;background-image:url('../images/back.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: bottom;}

.right { position:relative; float:right;width:580px; height:254px; text-align: left;padding:10px; margin-top:183px;}

.form {position:absolute;bottom:0; float:left; width:400px; padding:0px 0px 0px 36px; display:block; margin-bottom:4px;  }
```

I'm guessing that the problem is one of relationships between classes but I sure cant find it. Any help will be greatfully recieved.

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Site Coming Soon :: Company :: Company Description</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<!-- Loads Master CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">


<div class="box">
    <div class="content">



        <div class="right">
                <h2>Site coming soon.</h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                <h3>Sed diam nonummy.</h3>Sed diam nonummy. Nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad.
                <h3>Be informed:</h3>Enter your email address below and be notfied as soon as our site goes live.
                <div class="form">
                    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
                        <label>
                            <input type="text" name="emailForm" id="emailForm" />
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="notify me" />
                         </label>
                    </form>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="footer">
    &copy; Company Ltd 2011. Company registered in England and Wales. Registered Company Number 0000000. 
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would help if you could add your HTML. It would further help if you could create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) test case.

Comment: Here's my doctype reference:<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: added the HTML. Hope the formatting is acceptable.

Comment: I put your code here - http://jsbin.com/uwuga4. What is it supposed to look like? A screenshot would probably help. Which versions of Internet Explorer do you need to support? Bear in mind that you're testing with IE9, but when you press "compatibility mode", it's like you're using IE7 (a much buggier/older browser).

Comment: That jsbin highlights the problem perfectly. Hit the compatability view button and the form jumps way out to the right. I take your point about the older, buggier browser and might not worry about it. If there were a cross-browser compatible way to align these elements however, I would use it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and help everyone. Since I changed the margins on my text div, IE seems to properly handle my form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when looking at CSS, I find a good analogy is the cardboard boxes analogy, by this I mean you start with one cardboard box and place other boxes inside the big one. If the intended "inner" boxes are too big they will break the first box and everything falls out of the box.

So my first observation would be that your wrappers height is set to 380px where as your box is at 553px this will immediately break your box.

now we move on to the crux of the problem your understanding of positioning within CSS you have floated your wrapper left, I would think expecting that everything inside will then fall into place within that wrapper.

You then proceed to position absolute elements, this essentially removes the control of the positioning from being relative to the wrapper which you floated left, it is now to an extent relative to the top left corner of your screen (although this is not entirely true in every case).

You will need to change your positioning to relative and remove the height from your wrapper, their by fixing the box model and allowing the positioning of your copyright to be relative to the boxes it is next to within your HTML.

hope this helps